# add Array of Object in an object coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I wish to add an array of objects in an object in coffeescript
can't seem to be doing this
Here's what I've tried :

```
params = 
  zone: "test"
  currency: "USD"
  products: [
    {
      name: "product"
      ID: "id"
    },
    {
      name: "product2"
      ID: "id2"          
    }
  ]
```

the problem is on the products part.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `,` for specifying element of array.

```
params = 
  zone: "test"
  currency: "USD"
  products: [
    {
      name: "product"
      ID: "id"
    }
    {
      name: "product2"
      ID: "id2"          
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you posted compiles fine for me.

Instead of losing the `,`, you can lose the brackets:

```
params = 
  zone: "test"
  currency: "USD"
  products: [
      name: "product"
      ID: "id"
    ,
      name: "product2"
      ID: "id2"          
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to point the tricky part in @Markus answer.

Notice the `,` between the two objects, which is one level outer in indentation than the objects.

```
[
        name: "product"
        ID: "id"
    ,
        name: "product2"
        ID: "id2"
]
```

this would result in: `[ { name: 'product', ID: 'id' }, { name: 'product2', ID: 'id2' } ]`

Whereas putting the comma in the same level as the object

```
[
    name: "product"
    ID: "id"
    ,
    name: "product2"
    ID: "id2"
]
```

results in `[ { name: 'product2', ID: 'id2' } ]`